# JavaScript counter function with array parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create the following JavaScript to be used on a webpage.

Function: counter

Parameter: An array of numbers.

Returns: The numbers of negative elements, zeros, and values greater than zero in the given array.
Note: You must use a switch statement in the function.

I have very limited knowledge on scripting

Comment: I'll make it for $50/hr for you. But this sounds like homework.

Comment: We'll help with homework problems, but only if you demonstrate some sort of a coherent attempt, explaining where you got stuck, and what the problem with your own attempts are. Otherwise the question will be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @user1991965 post your code, surely you can minimally stub out a function that takes some parameters and returns something.

Comment: I have very limited scripting knowledge.. i dont know which function to use here.. i no we would use a switch instead of an if statement

Comment: What input do you have, what output do you expect?

Comment: the input would be numbers entered by user... and output counter of each negetave, zero and positive elements

Comment: Hint: see answer below.

Answer (score 3):

What if he is in love with arts, hates programming and just want to get through high school? If all this is not true I am happy to remove the answer :) I always wished someone would write all the essays on literature instead of me..

```
var counter = function (numbers) {
    var i,
        count = {
            negative: 0,
            zero: 0,
            positive: 0
        };

    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        switch (true) {
            case (numbers[i] < 0):
                count.negative++;
                break;

            case (numbers[i] === 0):
                count.zero++;
                break;

            case (numbers[i] > 0):
                count.positive++;
                break;
        }
    }

    return count;
};
```

Comment: While this answer does solve his issue (assuming this is indeed hw), you just helped him cheat, and if his teacher sees this, he will fail or worse. We all have to learn things we don't like, and you can't get other people to answer everything in life. Anywho, only my opinion. Not gonna downvote or anything, just saying.